# Use a Function in MySql update statement

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli, sql-update

I'm trying to use this mysql statement in a **cron.php** file to update one DB from another.

I need to remove all special characters in one column to save it in my first DB. I've defined a fuction where it's responsible for removing all of them, but when I try to run it in my column data,  it just doesn't work as expected.

I'm using the following code:

```
//função para retirada de acentos
function tirarAcentos($string){
   $acentos  =  'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûýýþÿŔŕ ';
   $sem_acentos  =  'aaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuuybsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuyybyRr-';
   $string = strtr($string, utf8_decode($acentos), $sem_acentos);
   //$string = str_replace(" ","-",$string);
   return utf8_decode($string);
}

// Executa o UPDATE de Cidades
 $sql = "UPDATE imo_imo2019.categoria categoria
        INNER JOIN imo_nido.i_cidade i_cidade
        ON categoria.categoria_id = i_cidade.codcidade
        SET categoria.categoria_title = i_cidade.descricao, categoria.categoria_url = tirarAcentos(i_cidade.descricao)";
```

The code is working fine. It's updating data as expected, but not removing the characters.

I'd really enjoy if some of you guys could help me to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: No, you cannot invoke a php function from within a SQL query. You would need to rewrite your php code as a MySQL function.

Comment: I'm using it in a PHP page. Am I supposed to change it even tough ?

Comment: I don't see where you are calling the sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SQL query runs in the database server not in PHP. You use PHP to generate a text representing the query then ask the database to run it. In your case you have two options:

1. Two separate queries, first a SELECT query to get the existing data, then a new UPDATE query for *each* row with the formatted value.
2. Write a [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) (a function in the database server) that does what you need.

Answer (score -1):

There are two solutions:

- Translate your function to a stored procedure on the database.
- get the data from the DB to PHP, apply your function, and update the DB with the changed values.